# php obtain current timestamp using DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, date-formatting

I understand that sql uses the datetime format of:

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

I am trying to gather a current timestamp in `php` and format it so that I can use it in a `UPDATE` query for `SQL`

I am having problems getting the current timestamp. I am trying:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date;
```

Nothing echos. I also tried:

```
$date = new DateTime('Y-m-d h:i:s');
echo $date;
```

and still nothing.

Any suggestions on getting the DateTime to capture the current timestamp

Comment: *and still nothing* Nothing ? You should get a BIG exception warning.

Comment: @Rizier123 page loaded blank // only thing on it was what I put above

Comment: Add error reporting at the top of your file(s): `<?php ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
echo (new DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Most of what I found was for the `date` syntax, but I was having problems finding useful `DateTime` information. This works great. It also looks like it's in the same format for SQL so theoretically i should be able to go back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with John Conde answer. But I would include, before that piece of code, the time zone setting:

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

Change "Sao Paulo" to your target timezone.

Comment: Actually, if you're going to be concerned with timezones, DateTimeZone() is the better way to go when using DateTime()